# How to change taskbar items size in gtk2.0 (gnome)?

Tags: gtk, size, gnome, taskbar

How can I change the size of the openwindow buttons in my taskbar in gtk2 (gnome). At the moment the title of my open windows is cut off "My Window Na...." when I want to see the full name  "My Window Name". The size of the items in the taskbar autoadjusts, so even if I shrink the text size they items get smaller as well. I am hoping there is a setting file I can edited to set a minimum size ?